# What are the required headers and body to upload a new item?

Tags: autodesk-data-management

I'm calling the **/data/v1/projects/:ProjectId:/storage** endpoint to create a new storage entry for Data Management API, but I'm getting invalid/missing parameters.

What's the required header & body for this call to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call endpoint /data/v1/projects/:ProjectId:/storage with

Header:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'
```

Body:

```
{
    data: {
        type: 'object',
        attributes: {
            name: theFileNameHere
        },
        relationships: {
            target: {
                data: {
                    type: 'folders',
                    id: folderIdHere
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More details [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-storage-POST/)